# Spring MVC & Tiles : Could not resolve view with name

Tags: java, spring, tiles, tiles-3

I hava a spring 3.2 application using tiles 3.0.1. Every thing works fine for months in local,prod everywhere (tomcat7).

On a newly bougth server (ws2019) with tomcat 9 (running with a dynamic password service account) :

The application start, can serve js, css, or json in REST controller but not JSP views with this error :

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name
> 'home' in servlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

I have no idea what is wrong. On my local it works (also tomcat 9).

I dig inside Spring and tiles and found that view are cached with a locale as a key : (CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO).

Maybe there is an issue the the server locale ?

I don't know, how can I debug this (whithout remote debugging ) ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from the war name and its version :

> AHEAD##val_1.4.6f.war

The tiles is looking for the file :

> BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO - File Resource
> file:/D:/apache-tomcat-9.0.56/webapps/AHEAD%23%23val_1.4.6f/WEB-INF/tiles.xml
> at
> file:/D:/apache-tomcat-9.0.56/webapps/AHEAD%23%23val_1.4.6f/WEB-INF/tiles.xml
> not found, continue

where the # are url encoded in %23 ...
Without the version it works...

Now I have to find a way to make it works with the version.

Comment: Using the latest tiles version fixed the issue